# Client And Server Architecture in Android

Tags: android

If i am using Location Listener interface in android to track locations in a project then  will it be a client server architecture?As far as i know it tracks location by requesting the server and therefore Google play needs to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while using LocationListner you are listening GPS device in your mobile through some classes/methods.Google play needs to be installed because if you want show location on map it needs playservices.You have to be clear getting location and showing it on map are two different things.If you are looking for 
[Android client server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962139/android-client-server-application)

Comment: i need to show just the location by converting the longitudes and latitudes using geocoder which will be sent as an sms to the other person.So it wont be a client server architecture right?

Comment: Geocoder has to get location from google's server,to give back the location for your lat,long right?

Comment: ya Geocoder maps all the addresses of the region to the latitude and longitude and then returns us the address.i am tracking the location and thenm reverse geocoding in a project.So what should be the project category?ll it be client server architecture or something else?

Comment: it's just client application because you are not storing location in your server for later delivery or etc.